# Event listener not working after triggered once

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Hello All I am implementing an onClick event that triggers a random SQL query that prints 2 random names. My question is that after the button is pressed once then I need to refresh the page to work again. I am trying to post an example of code but I am getting errors for my indentation I fix them as mentioned but still cannot post. Any suggestions for improvement that help get into the community

Comment: If you want us to help then you'll need to provide more details, like your code for example. See: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You can also upload your code to pastebin.com for example and share the link here (but please make sure to read the links above before doing so.)